# UIButton event which pushes view controller called multiple times when clicked rapidly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, ibaction

I have a `UIButton` displayed in my `UIViewController`. This button is tied to the following IBAction through the xib (touchUpInside)

```
- (IBAction)messagesButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    ChatsViewController* chatsVC = [[ChatsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ChatsViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:chatsVC animated:YES];
}
```

I've noticed that during a login operation which temporarily hangs the UI, if the user repeatedly clicks on this button, when the login operation completes this event is triggered TWICE. This causes the following:

```
nested push animation can result in corrupted navigation bar
Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted.
```

Additionally when I go back from this view I end up on the same page with a visible status/nav bar and a black content area. At this point clicking the back button again causes a crash.

From what I understood iOS queues up interaction during periods of unresponsiveness, which might be the cause of this behaviour. A workaround I've added was just to disable userinteraction in the IBAction and re-enable in `viewWillAppear`. e.g.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    // ...
    [self.messagesButton setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
}

- (IBAction)messagesButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    [self.messagesButton setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    ChatsViewController* chatsVC = [[ChatsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ChatsViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:chatsVC animated:YES];
}
```

Is there a safer way to prevent this multi-touch?

Edit: I should mention I've tried enabling exclusiveTouch and also cannot reproduce this after login has completed and the UI is back to normal no matter how quickly I press this button.

Answer (score 0):

Seems odd to me that you'd have the ability to tap a "Chats" button when you're not logged in.

If you disable user interaction until the login process is complete, wouldn't that solve it?

`userInteractionEnabled` is appropriate.

Comment: That's what we ended up doing more or less. We added a HUD during the login process that dismisses upon success. Was just curious why this behaviour exists to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution to your question is

you should disable the button, once request is fired for Login,

and if request succeed then push to another view and if it's fail then enable login button

Answer (score 0):

Check `isSelected` property os button before changing its state.
If 'not' checked, then set it. Accordingly manage you's cdoe.